# Curl GET Request redirects me to a page to select location

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I want to get the html content from this link

https://store.nike.com/in/en_gb/pw/boys-shoes/7pvZoi3

and for this i have created the below curl request php script

```
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://store.nike.com/in/en_gb/pw/boys-shoes/7pvZoi3');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, '<Pasted_cookie>');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
$last = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

But the above script redirects me to the page that is showing me a screen to select region. 
Please help me as what i need to change to make the script work.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you, to use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org). In a first step, that will allow you to interact with the web site to close the location window. Then You can use Curl normally. All of this, should be in a script.

Comment: @KubiRoazhon, Can you provide me a reference link that will be helpful to achieve to this task?

Answer (score 0):

To set location, there is always a network call that set your location in cookies or somewhere else, totally web dependent.
What you can do is, find that call, first mock the location call to set location then hit the main page with same cookies.